# InDesign: Pantone goes darker when placing .psd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, color, print-design, pantone

I have a very basic (so far) document with just a background set to `Pantone 333 C` as you can see here:

[image]

However, there is a `.psd` file that I am trying to place into the doc... and when I do, the whole document goes darker looking like the below:

[image]

As a little test, I have also created a random CMYK swatch (in this case, orange)... and when I set the background to that, it makes no difference to its colour whether the `psd` is there or not.

For some reason, just the Pantone colour just looks darker when I place the `psd` on top of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Indd, make sure **View > Overprint preview** is ON.

Or **Window > Output > Separations Preview** then select "Separations".

[image: overprint preview]

Please note this is just a display setting, that shouldn't affect the final results.

Th"INK" !

Answer (score 0):

ON ID's View menu, look at the **Proof Colours** option. Is it unselected before you place the psd and is it selected after?

This may account for the colour shift you are seeing, but I'd have to dig a little more to determine why is seems to be happening automatically, i.e. as a result of placing.

Comment: thanks — I've checked *Proof Colours* but it's always deselected. I've just had a look at the *Image Import Options* too, do you think maybe it has something to do with *Rendering Intent*?

Comment: ...also I've just converted the *.psd* to a *.jpg* and I don't have the issue with that for some reason

Comment: IN ID's general preferences, is the setting 'Allow incoming spot color to replace existing swatch of same name' selected? That may be relevant if the psd file has the same colour name but the colour is defined differently,

Comment: Best guess is it's a transparency display issue. When you converted the file to a jpg you removed any transparency information in the file.